# Waiting result of a task/service in a FragmentDispatcher

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I'm currently facing an issue : I need to wait the result of my request in order to return a value. Here is a sample of my FragmentDispatcher's class

```
public static Fragment getFragment(){
    switch (value) {
      case "1":
        // returns a fragment
        break;

      case "2":
        // returns another fragment
        break;

      case "3":
        // returns the correct fragment according to an async task or a Service response value
      break;
    }
    // returns default fragment
}
```

My case is the third : I need to wait the task or the service to be finished in order to returns the fragment according of the response value of the async task (in fact, it's a boolean). Because of the Async Task is .. asynchronous, my function returns immediately the default fragment.

Anyone to help resolving that ?

Comment: Waiting for the results asynchronous request usually defeats the purpose of making the request asynchronous in the first place.  For example if you try that on the uI thread you'll get an Application Not Responding error.   You're going to have to change your design.  For example this method could return null to mean "I don't know what fragment"  And the end of the asynchronous task could trigger some kind of retry. This is probably too big a change to be covered in a Stack Overflow answer (or comment!)

Comment: Thanks for your comment and I agree that using an async task is a really bad way to do. What about Service or IntentService I also mentionned ? Is there any way to retrieve the result with an EventBus we catched in the class thanks to a onEventMainThread method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem just by calling getFragment() method in an AsyncTask. Once it's done, I launch the fragment in postExecute()